# Wildcards or regular expressions in paths in Jekyll configuration

Tags: regex, jekyll, wildcard

In my Jekyll configuration file, I have the following "defaults" section:

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: pages/en
    values:
      lang: en
      direction: ltr
  -
    scope: 
      path: pages/he
    values:
      lang: he
      direction: rtl
  -
    scope:
      path: topics/en
    values:
      lang: en
      direction: ltr
  -
    scope: 
      path: topics/he
    values:
      lang: he
      direction: rtl
```

There is obvious duplication here. I would like to tell Jekyll to treat all paths that end with "en" in the same way and all paths that end with "he" in the same way, like this:

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: */en
    values:
      lang: en
      direction: ltr
  -
    scope: 
      path: */he
    values:
      lang: he
      direction: rtl
```

But this does not work.

Is there another way to achieve this goal?

Comment: What about `path: **/he`? just a guess here!

Answer (score 2):

Not currently supported in Jekyll, but it looks like someone wrote a plugin to allow regex's in the `scope.path` https://github.com/gjtorikian/jekyll-conrefifier, but the open issue suggests that it won't work with Jekyll 3.x. Might be worth asking for the feature here: https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/specifying-multiple-paths-or-types-in-front-matter-defaults-scope/583/7